# AWS Lambda post SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am french.
I want to create a simple lambda to send a SNS notification when an element is added in my dynamoDB.

In my lambda, I add a triger to my dynamo table and I have put this code :

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  

exports.handler = function(event, context) {  
    console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    sns.publish({
        Message: 'Test publish to SNS from Lambda',
        TopicArn: '#####'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);
        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
    });
};
```

It works perfectly, I receive the notifications.
But when I clear the code and I add an sns destination routing to my topic, it doesn't work. no message is sent.

What is the difference between using aws-sdk and add a sns destination to the lambda ?

Thank you very much for your response.

Here is what I would like to have:
[image: lambda]

With the lambda code below :

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean? Which SNS destination? How do you invoke your function? What does it mean "when I clean the code"?

Comment: Could you be more specific with `it doesn't work`?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.
I just want to know if it is possible to replace my lambda code by just add a SNS destination.
I add a SNS destination specifying the arn of my topic. I execute my lambda but no message is sent.